# Saving model and loading model on a separate session gives wrong predictions

Tags: tensorflow, keras, classification, conv-neural-network, prediction

As soon as training is finished, generating predictions on the testing dataset gives an accuracy > 70.

Then I save the model using `model.save(...)` method.

When Trying to load the model in a separate session, the predictions are around 20s.

I can confirm that i'm using the same testing dataset and same preprocessing steps that I've done when predicting after training.

To get over with the doubt on the different tokenizers, I've saved the tokenizer to a `tokenizer.pickle` file which will be loaded before conducting `texts_to_sequences` and `pad_sequences` on the testing text data (this didn't make any difference).

I've tried compiling the model after loading before making predictions, this didn't work as well.

```
model.save('model.h5') #for saving the model
------------------------------------------------------------

#Predicting after saving on a different session

trained_model = load_model('model.h5') #for loading the model in a different session.

# load tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
with open('trained_model/tokenizer.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
  tokenizer = pickle.load(handle)

test_revs = pd.read_csv('test_dataset.csv')

test_revs.loc[:, 'rating'] = test_revs['rating'].apply(points_to_class) #converting decimal ratings to integer classes 

actual_texts = test_revs['text']
actual_ratings = test_revs['rating']

final_Y_test = to_categorical(actual_ratings, 5)

actual_text_tokens = add_doc_to_vocab(actual_texts.tolist())

sequences_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(actual_text_tokens)

X_test = pad_sequences(sequences_test, maxlen=1939, padding='post')

# Predictions
pred_test = trained_model.predict(X_test)
pred_test = [np.argmax(x) for x in pred_test]

# Actual
true_test = final_Y_test
true_test = [np.argmax(x) for x in true_test]

# Find accuracies
accuracy = accuracy_score(true_test, pred_test)

print("The total accuracy is : ", accuracy)
```

I'm new to TensorFlow, if anyone has any suggestions, please raise, cheers !

Comment: Have you compared the raw feature vector?

Comment: Along with saving and reloading the model, kindly save the model weights after the training and load the model weights before prediction.

Comment: After doing some comparison, seems like the save and load model works as expected and its the data which causes this issue. The pre-processing of the text data needs the same tokenizer instance that was used in the training session. And pre-processing of labels also causes the issue, I'm using the same method `final_Y_test = to_categorical(actual_ratings, 5)` in the training session as well, but not sure why this causes the difference.